# how to make Intersection Observer to replicate bootstrap scroll spy behavior

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm building a `blazor` application where I should keep java script code to minimal. So I'm using only bootstrap css in my parallax page. I have made scroll spy like behavior work with `window.onscroll` since it cannot be done with `c#` as of now; but it gives poor performance.

After googling, I recently came across `IntersectionObserver` API. so I thought of making my existing `window.onscroll` logic to work with `IntersectionObserver` API. However I'm not able to achieve it.

Here is what I'm trying to do. In my parallax page with fixed top nav bar and I would like to apply `active` css class to `a.nav-items` when the user scroll reaches the respective section he wants to view.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-nav" data-offset="55">

  <header id="page-hero" class="site-header d-flex flex-column align-content-between">

    <nav class="site-nav family-sans navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myTogglerNav" aria-controls="myTogglerNav"
          aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" href="#page-hero">
          <i class="fas fa-cube mr-2"></i> Layout Components</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myTogglerNav">
          <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto font-weight-regular text-uppercase">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-hero">home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-multicolumn">columns</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-media">media</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-photogrid">grid</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-carousel">carousel</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-nested">nested</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-icons">icons</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-floater">floater</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-cards">cards</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="layout-hero jumbotron jumbotron-fluid d-flex align-items-center mt-5 text-reverse">
      <div class="container text-center">
......
......
......

    <article id="page-multicolumn" class="page-section vertical-padding">

    <header class="page-section-header container">
.....
.....
.....

    <article id="page-media" class="page-section vertical-padding">

    <header class="page-section-header container text-center">
....
```

I have `article` tag with `id` matching `href` of `a` in top `.nav-item`. I have only pasted few of the html as the skeleton is same for all article tags.

Here is my existing `window.onscroll`:

```js
var sections = {};

document.querySelectorAll(".page-section,.site-header").forEach(section => sections[section.id] = section.offsetTop);

window.onscroll = function () {
    document.querySelector('header nav').classList.toggle('inbody', document.documentElement.scrollTop > 380);
    document.querySelector('#page-media .layout-animation').style['visibility'] = 'hidden';

    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    Object.keys(sections).forEach(key => {
        if (sections[key] <= scrollPosition + 55) {
            document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-item').forEach(a => a.classList.remove('active'));
            document.querySelector('a[href="#' + key + '"]').classList.add('active');

            if (key === 'page-media') {
                document.querySelector('#page-media .layout-animation').classList.add('animated', 'fadeInRight');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The above code works. But I would like to use the right API.

Here is my `IntersectionObserver`:

```js
if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        (entries, observer) => {
            console.log(entries);
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                /* Here's where we deal with every intersection */
                document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-item').forEach(a => a.classList.remove('active'));
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    document.querySelector('header nav').classList.toggle('inbody', entry.target.id !== 'page-hero');
                    document.querySelector('#page-media .layout-animation').style['visibility'] = 'hidden';
                    document.querySelector('a[href="#' + entry.target.id + '"]').classList.add('active');
                    if (entry.target.id === 'page-media') {
                        document.querySelector('#page-media .layout-animation').classList.add('animated', 'fadeInRight');
                    }
                }
            });
        }, { root: document.querySelector('.site-nav'), rootMargin: "0px", threshold: 0 });
    document.querySelectorAll('.page-section,.site-header').forEach(section => observer.observe(section));
}
```

But my intersection observer is not working. I tired using `console.log(entry)` to see what happens. All the entries gets logged only on page load and not working after that. Please assist on where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code here doesn't work is that it's running at the wrong time. The call to `document.querySelectorAll('.page-section,.site-header')` needs to be executed after those elements have been rendered into the DOM, otherwise it won't match anything.

Here is how I made it to work, I tweaked the function little bit as shown below,

```js
function highlightMenu() {
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.page-section,.site-header');
    const config = {
        rootMargin: '-55px 0px -85%'
    };

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function
        (entries, self) {

        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                intersectionHandler(entry);
            }
        });
    }, config);

    sections.forEach(section => observer.observe(section));
}

function intersectionHandler(entry) {
    const id = entry.target.id;
    document.querySelector('header nav').classList.toggle('inbody', id !== 'page-hero');
    if (id === 'page-media') {
        document.querySelector('#page-media .layout-animation').classList.add('animated', 'fadeInRight');
    }

    const currentlyActive = document.querySelector('nav a.nav-item.active');
    const shouldBeActive = document.querySelector('nav a.nav-item[href="#' + id + '"]');

    if (currentlyActive) {
        currentlyActive.classList.remove('active');
    }
    if (shouldBeActive) {
        shouldBeActive.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

and called from inside my component `OnAfterRenderAsync` using JS interop in blazor,

```cs
@code{

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("highlightMenu");
        }
    }

}
```